# Parallel programming in go using GOMAXPROCS

Tags: go, parallel-processing

I have seen people setting `runtime.GOMAXPROCS` to `runtime.NumCPU()` to enable ***parallel*** processing in go. [Official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) doesn't say anything about the upper bound of `GOMAXPROCS`; can I set this to any arbitrary positive integer or should it always be less than eq. to  `NumCPU` value?

I tried setting it to a number that's greater than the `#` of ***logical*** cores, my code works just fine

Comment: Max is `256`, I updated my answer (was trying to remember bit shift placements by memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The max is 256**; but note, it will not error if you set it higher.

https://golang.org/src/runtime/debug.go?s=534:560#L7

```
12  // GOMAXPROCS sets the maximum number of CPUs that can be executing
13  // simultaneously and returns the previous setting.  If n < 1, it does not
14  // change the current setting.
15  // The number of logical CPUs on the local machine can be queried with NumCPU.
16  // This call will go away when the scheduler improves.
17  func GOMAXPROCS(n int) int {
18      if n > _MaxGomaxprocs {
19          n = _MaxGomaxprocs
20      }
21      lock(&sched.lock)
22      ret := int(gomaxprocs)
23      unlock(&sched.lock)
24      if n <= 0 || n == ret {
25          return ret
26      }
27  
28      stopTheWorld("GOMAXPROCS")
29  
30      // newprocs will be processed by startTheWorld
31      newprocs = int32(n)
32  
33      startTheWorld()
34      return ret
35  }
```

`Line 19` sets the total number to `_MaxGomaxprocs`.

Which is...

https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime2.go?h=_MaxGomaxprocs#L407

```
const (
    // The max value of GOMAXPROCS.
    // There are no fundamental restrictions on the value.
    _MaxGomaxprocs = 1 << 8
)
```

That bitshift in binary form is `100000000` and 1 is an `int` which on 64bit systems Go makes that an Int64, which means **the max is 256**.  (32bit systems with `int` in Go would be int32, but same value of 256)

Now, as far as setting this to more than your number of cores - it all depends on your workload and CPU context switching that is happening (e.g. how many locks does your go program force to happen, or do you use `mutex.Lock()` everywhere, etc).

Remember, Golang abstracts away the context switching if it needs to happen or not.

Benchmarking is your friend here.  If your app runs 10,000 goroutines with little to no cpu context switching (following good design patterns), then yes bump that sucker to 256 and let it ride.  If you app chokes and creates a lot of CPU wait-time with context switching/threads, then set it to 8 or 4 even to give it room to breath with all that `mutex` locking going on.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't need to mess with `GOMAXPROCS` most of the time since the runtime interacts with the OS for you.  `GOMAXPROCS` used to default to 1, but with Go 1.5, it now defaults to the `NumCPU()`

Setting it higher than NumCPU will only give the scheduler more (unnecessary) work for dealing with OS threads.

Comment: Expanding on that, I would like to note that it is a misconception that one can "enable parallel processing" by fiddling with `GOMAXPROCS`. There is no _guarantee_ whatsoever that goroutines are run in parallel (as opposed to concurrent), even with `GOMAXPROCS`>1.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Well, do you know any "guaranteed" way of enabling parallel processing in go ?

Comment: @ShanValleru, the design of Go's concurrency model is that you should not need to think about parallelizing, that is the runtime's job.

Comment: @matt.s I see. Comment's from the go runtime core does say that GOMAXPROCS will go away as the scheduler improves; I am not sure if trusting the runtime with parallelization is a good thing, though. I may have to do some research to understand more

Comment: Correct, don't usually need to mess with it. But for certain apps with specific concurrency designs (and avoiding mutex locking), you can get significant performance boosts by increasing it to 256.  I have benchmarked complex code that got over 500% increase in speed going from 8 to 256.  Blanketly stating it will give your schedule only more *unnecessary* work is pure opinion.

Comment: @eduncan911, you are absolutely right.  I just worry, that someone is reaching for GOMAXPROCS for parallelism first, when they should have tried and tested several other methods that are built in to the language (and tooling) before they need to start touching the tuning knobs on the runtime itself.

Comment: yep. proper architecture is paramount. that's why I highly promote benchmarks beside tests.  great way to see advantages, or disadvantages.